# Energy of electrons?

Tags: electrons, electronic-band-theory

Whats meant by energy of electrons in different orbits of atoms. Does this means that the electrons at higher evergy levels have more kinetic energy as compared to the electrons at lower energy level or it means something else ? Energy we all know is the ability to do any work ? So what kind of more work electrons can perform which are at higher energy levels ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electron energy in different energy eigenstates of atoms is the total energy which can be considered to be the sum of kinetic and potential energy. Electrons in higher energy levels of an atom can perform work when dropping to a lower energy level by emitting a photon (i.e., an electromagnetic wave). The work done by an electron in dropping from a higher to a lower energy level can also be converted into kinetic energy of another electron (Auger electron emission).

Comment: why the electrons farther from the nucleus are supposed to have more energy ? whats the reason that they have more energy.

Comment: The reason is analogous to the orbital energy of planets. The basic reason for the increase of total energy of the higher energy eigenstates of the atom is the increase in potential Coulomb energy (becoming less negative) of the electron with increasing distance from the nucleus.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

"Hence a system comprising of an electron far off from the nucleus will have high potential energy stored in it, indicating they have sufficient potential energy that can overcome the attractive forces (means the attractive forces between the electron and the nucleus is less). This means the potential energy liberated by an electron far from the nucleus is very less. Hence the outermost electrons are less stable.

For an electron very close to the nucleus, the potential energy is minimum, which means the system comprising of nucleus and a nearer electron liberates most of it's potential energy (so that the system will now have a lesser potential energy) to have an increased attractive force, which in turn corresponds to maximum stability.

So a large amount of energy is required to liberate an electron from an inner most shell rather than an electron from the outermost shell. This is why we say that the electron in the outermost shell has a higher (potential) energy than the inner most shells. So a less amount of energy is needed to liberate the electron from the outermost shell."

Comment: Whom are you quoting ?